# How do I externally access a service with kubernetes NodePort?

Tags: kubernetes

I've setup a NodePort service using the following config:

**wordpress-service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: wordpress
  name: wordpress
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: wordpress
```

Is this sufficient to access the service externally, if so how can I now access the service? What details do I need - and how do I determine them - for example node IP.

Comment: For test and development this should be fine. Run `kubectl get svc` wordpress, you can see the nodePort number. Then you can access the service with NodeIP:NodePort

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you define a service as type `NodePort`, **every** node in your cluster will proxy that port to your service. If you nodes are reachable from outside the Kubernetes cluster, you should be able to access the service at `nodeIP:nodePort`.

To determine `nodeIP` of a particular node, you can use either `kubectl get no <node> -o yaml` or `kubectl describe no <node>`. The `status.Addresses` field will be of interest. Generally, you will see fields like `HostName`, `ExternalIP` and `InternalIP` there.

To determine `nodePort` of your service, you can use either `kubectl get svc wordpress -o yaml` or `kubectl describe svc wordpress`. The `spec.ports.nodePort` is the port you need.

Answer (score 7):

> For Kubernetes on GCE:

We had the same question regarding services of type NodePort: How do we access node port services from our own host?

@ivan.sim 's answer (nodeIp:nodePort) is on mark however, you still wouldn't be able to access your service unless you add a firewall ingress (inbound to google cloud) traffic rule on the VPC network console to allow your host to be able to access your compute node

[image]
the above rule is dangerous and should be used only during development

You can find the node port using either the Google Cloud console or by running subsequent kubectl commands to find out the node running your pod which has your container. i.e `kubectl get pods , kubectl describe pod your-pod-name, kubectl describe node node-that-runs-you-pod` .status.addresses has your ExternalIP

It would be great if we could extract the node ip running our container in the pod using only a `label/selector` and a few line of commands, so here is what we did, in this case our selector is `app: your-label`:

```
$ nodename=$(kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{.items[?(@.metadata.labels.app=="your-label")].spec.nodeName}')

$ nodeIp=$(kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{.items[?(@.metadata.name=="'$(echo $nodename)'")].status.addresses[?(@.type=="ExternalIP")].address}')

$ echo nodeIp
```

**notice**: we used json path to extract the information we desired, for more on json path see: [json path](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/jsonpath/)

You could certainly turn this into a script that takes a label/selector as input and outputs an external ip of the node running your container !!!

To get the nodeport just type:

```
$ kubectl get services
```

under the **PORT(S)** columns you will see something like tagetPort:nodePort. this nodeport  is what you want .

```
nodeIp:nodePort
```

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant and correct for GKE/GCP.  was banging my heads on the wall as to why I could not hit my service from outside and this was IT!

Answer (score 2):

Service defined like this got assgned a high port number and is exposed on all your cluster nodes on that port (probably something like 3xxxx). Hard to tell the rest without proper knowledge of how your cluster is provisioned. `kubectl get nodes` should give you some knowledge about your nodes.

Although I assume you want to expose the service to the outside world. In the long run I suggest getting familiar with LoadBalancer type services and Ingress / IngressController

Comment: Yes I want to access it externally. Unfortunately this won't work with a LoadBalancer service.

Comment: Why would it not work with LB service ? My "end-game" approach would be to deploy Ingress Controller exposed to the world with LB service type (usually gets it's own FQDN you can use as CNAME target for what you want to have for you), and then whatever you expose with Ingress on your cluster, can be reached on that LB service of IngressController

Comment: Apologies I meant my use case required NodePort instead of LoadBalancer.

Comment: Well, as LB service *is*  a NodePort service, I assume you do not have a working support for the LB in your k8s setup. To expose stuff on low, standard ports you might want to run IC or some other way of exposing services (ie. https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/service-loadbalancer) with a `hostNetwork: true` or with `hostPort` set. But it is hard to suggest something without deeper knowledge of your setup/use-case

Comment: LoadBalancer assumes your traffic is HTTP or some other stateless protocol they support. If you're using a stateful protocol on top of TCP, there's no way a load balancer will work. I don't even know what happens if you try that.

Comment: that is as far from truth as it can be. Practicaly all loadbalancers support LB on layer 3. Even pure iptables implementation that kube-proxy uses (effectively via conntrack support)