# Increasing TCP timeout of Internal Load Balancer/Ingress for Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, internal-load-balancer

I see that for Layer 7 traffic [one can set the timeout window](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service). However, I am wanting to do this for Layer 4/TCP traffic. Is this possible?

Comment: How are you creating Load Balancer? Manually or as a service?

Comment: @Crou My plan is to create it as a service.

Comment: If you do it as a service then it will work internally, if you expose the NodePort it will act as a socket.

Comment: But how do I make a connection to the node port from my VM on the same network?

Comment: This question was answered - [How do I externally access a service with kubernetes NodePort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802336/how-do-i-externally-access-a-service-with-kubernetes-nodeport)